# What is the difference between ASN.1 and SMI?

Tags: snmp, asn.1

From my understanding:

ASN.1 has a wide area of use, and SMI is a subset of ASN.1 which is used specifically in SNMP.

Is this correct? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASN.1 is standardized notation.  From RFC 2578, it appears that SMI uses that notation, much as I am presently using the English grammar to construct these sentences.  For example, in section 2, they give:

```
SNMPv2-SMI DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
   -- the path to the root
   org            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { iso 3 }  --  "iso" = 1
```

This text follows the ASN.1 syntax for defining an ASN.1 module ("SNMPv2-SMI"), with the first definition in the module being an ASN.1 value ("org") having a particular ASN.1 type ("OBJECT IDENTIFIER").

Further, RFC 2578 places restrictions on the ASN.1 notation that may be used.  As an example, in 3.1 they restrict ASN.1 identifiers from using hyphens, which would otherwise be allowed.  This is like saying that in a StackOverflow post, we'll use sentences according to the English grammar, but sentences using the past tense are not allowed.

Side note: RFC 2578 is using ASN.1 1988. Newer versions of the ASN.1 standard exist, and some of the notation from the 1988 standard was eliminated (in particular, macros).

Comment: I've read in various places e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_of_Management_Information that SMI is "an adapted subset of ASN.1". I was always hazy if 'adapted' had a special meaning here, but I think your answer means it is only restrictions (with zero changes or additions) compared to ASN.1 ?

Comment: @k1eran I haven't studied the SMI RFC enough to be able to say whether they add any notation that isn't supported by ASN.1.  I wondered the same thing about that word "adapted".  A quick perusal makes me think they could have omitted the word "adapted" and avoided the confusion it might cause, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: @Kevin: Am i correct that all SMI notation is valid in ASN.1 but some asn.1 notation may not be valid in SMI.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha Definitely some ASN.1 notation is disallowed in SMI.  If SMI truly used a subset of ASN.1, all SMI notation would be valid ASN.1, but whether it does truly use a subset, I don't know.  Paul Thorpe's answer suggests they did not use true subset.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as much as the ASN.1 committee over the years tried to get the IETF to use actual ASN.1 for SNMP, the group responsible for SNMP deviated from ASN.1 in various ways which make it impossible for general purpose ASN.1 Tools to fully handle SNMP MIBs.  They not only use the withdrawn ASN.1 MACRO notation, but use it in such a way that even ASN.1 Tools which still support the obsolete ASN.1 MACRO notation cannot properly handle the MIB definitions.  You need a special tool created specifically for SNMP MIBs to fully parse and handle them properly.

Comment: Though not on the same scale, it has a passing resemblence to the Oracle/Google fracas over Java: Stop Messing With Our Stuff!

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what's on the text book. Read IETF RFC 1155 and 2578 for more details.

Comment: yes , its there in RFC , but the definition present in RFC is little technical to understand , Can you tell me in layman terms , which is just simple to understand.